# Consulta y obtención de registros

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subconsultas

Me encuentro en una encrucijada la cual no sé si se pueda realizar.

Resulta que estoy haciendo una busqueda de un registro, es fácil si solo se trata de una tabla, pero no, el registro se debe buscar en varias tablas (5 o más en total), he intentado realizar la consulta por INNER JOIN, pero no hay ningún campo que conecte las tablas, si,

```html
SELECT MAC FROM TABLA1 IF NOT EXIST SELECT MAC TABLA 2 WHERE MAC = '12345'
```

las 5 tablas tienen dos campos ID y MAC, pero ninguna MAC se repite en ninguna tabla. No sé como hacerlo.

¿Hay alguna forma de buscar un registro, y si no lo encuentra en una tabla, pase a la otra?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que el número de tablas es fijo, la opción que me parece más directa es hacer una **UNION**

```
SELECT MAC FROM TABLA1 WHERE MAC = '12345' UNION
SELECT MAC FROM TABLA2 WHERE MAC = '12345' UNION
...
SELECT MAC FROM TABLA5 WHERE MAC = '12345';
```

Si quieres saber de qué tabla sale el registro:

```
SELECT MAC, 'Tabla 1' FROM TABLA1 WHERE MAC = '12345' UNION
SELECT MAC, 'Tabla 2' FROM TABLA2 WHERE MAC = '12345' UNION
...
SELECT MAC, 'Tabla 5' FROM TABLA5 WHERE MAC = '12345';
```

En todo caso, un modelo en que el mismo dato puede estar en cinco tablas distintas huele a mal diseño; igual es una opción hacer una tabla "maestra" de MACs y luego cinco tablas que referencien a la maestra.